# Actualizar datos en otra pantalla con diferente sesión al presionar un boton

Tags: php, javascript, sql, sql-server

Hola chicos estoy haciendo un sistema de turnos para colas con `PHP` y `SQL Server`  donde tengo el siguiente inconveniente: cada vez que presiono un botón  debe mostrar en pantalla el turno que corresponde pero no se como hacer esa integración de botón ya que actualmente lo hago con un query que consulta a la base de datos cada segundo pero cuando en internet está lento demora y no es funcional.

Comment: Deberías hacer la consulta asociada al evento onclick del botón, por ejemplo por ajax. La idea es que avances en el código y muestres lo que vas haciendo y dónde tienes problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Se puede realizar de dos formas:

1. Solicitar información cada intervalo de tiempo desde el cliente al servidor, no es la mas optima.
2. Usar html5 Sockets, esto te permitirá que el servidor actualice el/los clientes.

Enlaces que te pueden ayudar:

- [The Web Sockets API](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-websockets-20091222/)
- [Funciones de Socket - php](http://php.net/manual/es/ref.sockets.php)